# search into text file and get Line text if contain string php

Tags: php

I have text file which contain text like this

```
A8-30-AD   (hex)        WEIFANG GOERTEK ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD
A830AD     (base 16)        WEIFANG GOERTEK ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD
            Wei fang Export processing Zone
            Wei Fang  Shan Dong  261205
            CN

D8-68-C3   (hex)        Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
D868C3     (base 16)        Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
            #94-1, Imsoo-Dong
            Gumi  Gyeongbuk  730-350
```

this file contain all mac address and their vendor .
I want to search in to this file if line contain mac address which I search I want to get it's vendor 
for example, if I search for

> A8:30:AD

mac address in to this file it will return

> WEIFANG GOERTEK ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD

so I want only vendor name where (hex) string is found 
how can I do that with php

Answer (score 0):

You file has lines wich content

> key [space] (type) [space] name

And you want to fine "name" by "key"

1. So you can use preg-match-all() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php with pattern like this for search needed lines

   > /^$search\s+\(.*?\)\s+(.*)?\$/m

   if you want to search by part of key you can wrap you key in ".*?"

   > /^.*?$search.*?\s+\(.*?\)\s+(.*)?\$/m
2. Becouse you have in file keys wich content only letters and digits you can clear you serach by

   > /\W+/

   and search only by those lines

So you code

```
$search='A8:30:AD'; // search string;
$filename='data.txt'; // name of file with data



$search=preg_replace('/\W+/','',$search); // clear search, remove non-letters and non-digits
$filecontent = file_get_contents($filename);

$pattern = "/^$search\s+\(.*?\)\s+(.*)?\$/m"; //build the pattern

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $filecontent, $matches)){ // if found
    // print_r($matches[1]); // show found array with all matches
    echo $matches[1][0]; // show only first found
} else { 
    echo "nothing found";
}
```

You will get

> WEIFANG GOERTEK ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD

For searching by part of "key" use this

```
$pattern = "/^.*?$search.*?\s+\(.*?\)\s+(.*)?\$/m"; //build the pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to read the file and parse it, collecting the mac address and the corresponding vendor into an array with the mac address line as keys. something like `$arr = ['mac-address1' => 'vedor1', ....]` . so we do it this way

```
function getMacAddressVendor(string $mac_address) {
    static $database = NULL;
    if (is_null($database)) {
        $database = [];
        $handle = fopen('path to file', 'r');
        while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
            $matches = []; //we capture stuffs into this array
            $line = trim($line);
            //mac addresses are hexadecimals that may contain colon or dash
            if (preg_match('/^([A-E0-9\-:]+)\s+\([^)]+\)\s+(.+)$/i', $line, $matches) {
                $database[strtoupper($matches[1])] = $matches[2];
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return array_key_exists(strtoupper($mac_address), $database)? $database[$mac_address] : '';
}

$vendor = getMacAddressVendor('A8:30:AD');
```